# Adding a lib to yocto rootfs

Tags: yocto, spdlog

I am using [this](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-oe/recipes-support/spdlog/spdlog_1.8.0.bb) recipe, which by default doesn't copy the resulting .a lib (it expects header only usage I think)

I am trying to get the resultant libspdlog.a into my sysroot, but I can't seem to make that happen. I coppied the recipe to my layer (had to anyway because my project refereces an older version of meta-oe)

So far i've tried:

```
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libspdlog.a"
FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/libspdlog.a"
FILES_${PN}-staticdev += "${libdir}/libspdlog.a"
```

and

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    install -m 0644 libspdlog.a ${D}${libdir}
 }
```

I'm pretty sure do_install is not getting called.
I had to add to my IMAGE_INSTALL spd-dev so maybe this has something to do with it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`do_install` is right and for now just have `FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libspdlog.a"`.

If you have kept the same name of the recipe when you copied over you will need to add the following `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " spdlog"` (in either `local.conf` or an image recipe if you have one) to put into image.

To verify `do_install` is working ok:

- Inside your build folder (where you issue bitbake from) there will be `tmp/work` (if you haven't changed this in your `local.conf`)
- Find the location of your recipe folder `<recipe_name>/<recipe_version>` (eg. `spdlog/1.8.0-r0/`)
- Inside here there will be a `packages-split/spdlog` folder
- Inside this you should see your structure `usr/lib/libspdlog.a`

Comment: I have that file only in: tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5t2hf-neon-vfpv4/spdlog/usr/lib/libspdlog.a. Also for the image it has to be spdlog-dev. Maybe thats a clue? In the recipe itself it mentions something about header only...

Comment: Run `oe-pkgdata-util find-path /usr/lib/libspdlog.a` and add the package which has this file to your image. That should do it.